# Google Form Script to reset Responses (in the form not on the seets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is that possible to reset all responses on the form site (not in the sheets) with a script? 
Thanks
Vendel

Comment: Yes, this is well documented in the Apps Script reference: [delete all form responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteAllResponses()). Note that this does _not_ delete responses from a linked spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

response after a form being submitted, you can do the following

```
function myFunction() {

    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();

    // delete the response
    form.deleteAllResponses();
}
```

Make sure that you set a trigger for this function. You can specify that this function should be triggered when form is submitted.